# How do I use just created webhooks?

Tags: discord.py, webhooks

So, I'm using a script to create a channel and a webhook in it, and now I want to know how i can send a message with the webhook. My code:

```
@client.command(ctx, arg)
async def channelwebhook(ctx, arg):
  guild = ctx.message.guild
    channels = await guild.create_text_channel(arg)
    channels.create_webhook(name="Chong")
```

Comment: Oh, and I would like to use "arg" for the webhook message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Webhook.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook%20send#discord.Webhook.send):

```py
my_webhook = channels.create_webhook(name="Chong")
# or whatever here
# it's the same as the usual ctx.send
# so you can send embeds, etc
my_webhook.send(arg)
```